# Structure of tame concealed algebra of Euclidean type

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, quivers

I wanted to know some references where people have studied the representation theory of tame concealed algebra of Euclidean type. What do we know about the structure of their module category?  What kind of geometric problem have people considered for tame concealed algebra of Euclidean type.

For e.g.- we know that there exists a sincere
separating exact subcategory $R$ of $\mathrm{ind}\,A$ if and only if $A$ is a concealed-canonical algebra. This description of concealed canonical algebra was useful in understanding the ring of semi-invariant for these algebras (as you can see in the paper- "SEMI-INVARIANTS FOR CONCEALED-CANONICAL ALGEBRAS", by GRZEGORZ BOBINSKI)

Where can I read about some useful properties of tame concealed algebra of Euclidean type?

Comment: A good reference is C. M. Ringel, Tame algebras and integral quadratic forms, Springer Lecture Notes 1099, 1984. See the theorem in section 4.3, page 194.

Comment: @wcb Thanks a lot for the reference. What about piecewise hereditary algebra? Do we have something similar?